# htaccess 301 redirect with query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to setup an htaccess redirect with query just like this:

```
Redirect 301 /?page=services/branddevelopment /brand-development?
```

or this:

```
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^page=services/branddevelopment$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://domainname/   [R=301,L]
```

Am I missing something in here? Or a wrong syntax? It doesn't redirect the way I want it to be. Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual origin and to which page you want to redirect?

Comment: What is the error with 2nd `mod_rewrite` rule in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something in here? Or a wrong syntax? It doesn't redirect
>   the way I want it to be. Thanks!

You really didn't explain much about what is happening and the result you are getting so that someone can tell why you are getting the result you are getting.

However in *general* you can't use `mod_alias` (Redirect) to redirect a query string it won't work.

You have to use `mod_rewrite`, which it seems like you were trying to do. However you don't want to carry over the query string with the redirect so you need to use `?` in the rewrite URL.

So if you have a URL like so

```
http://www.example.com/?page=services/branddevelopment
```

Then your rule would be

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=services/branddevelopment$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/?   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yay! It worked, thanks! I should really keep this in mind when redirecting a query string.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer since it helped you.